# Using Python to build a linear regression model and find R2'd; cannot get the model to fit or predict

Tags: python, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

*Some imports for several reasons*

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

I successfully split the data -test(30%) and train(70%) and separated it:

```py
X_train = df_train.drop(columns='Rating')
y_train = df_train.Rating
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X_test = df_test.drop(columns='Rating')
y_test = df_test.Rating
```

Everything is fine to this point, then

```py
linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'GAME'
```

*Am positive the Rating column is a float*

Comment: can you check that you have read in the data correctly? if you do df_train.info(), you will see that your 'Rating' column is not float

Answer (score 0):

Check your df first row, it might have header repeating again in that place. or Just train from second row.

Comment: Thank you Sandeep, I am new at this and am not sure what you mean. Can you please elaborate more... Either way, thanks!

Comment: Sometimes what happens is that, the header repeats as the first row due to file formatting. So try removing the first row and perform the training.